# Bash hints does not work after sudo or man

Tags: bash, centos-6

I use Centos 6.5. `Tab` key on keyboard helps to insert command in terminal. E.g. if I write vi and press tab then all possible opportunities are printed:

```
$ vi
vi                vim               vino-passwd       virt-what
view              vimdiff           vino-preferences  visudo
vigr              vimtutor          vipw
```

But if i write `sudo vi` or `man vi` then hints does not work. It works properly on Ubuntu so I suppose that it should also work on Centos.

How to fix it?

```
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2959 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 3348 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the bash autocomplete package from the EPEL repo

I followed this [guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/fedora-redhat-scientific-linuxenable-bash-completion/) and it worked for me when I was looking for this feature in centos